# Применить стиль для диапазона двух дат html, css

Tags: css

Имеется календарь, например с input checked. Как сделать так чтобы при выборе например двух дат, например 5 и 10 применялись определенные стили к диапазону, тоесть к 5,6,7,8,9,10 при момощи только css и html? При помощи nth-child не получилось, так как заранее диапазон дат неизвестен. Подскажите хотябы в какую сторону копать. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:in-range
Возможно будет полезным

Answer (score 1):

```css
form { display: flex; flex-flow: row wrap; max-width: 15rem; }
form > [type="checkbox"] { display: none; }
form > label { width: 2rem; padding: 0.5rem 0; text-align: center; border: 1px solid transparent; }
form > :checked + label { border-color: #47a; }

form > :checked ~ :not(:checked ~ :checked + label ~ *) { background: #def; }
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-1"><label for="d-1">1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-2"><label for="d-2">2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-3"><label for="d-3">3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-4"><label for="d-4">4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-5"><label for="d-5">5</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-6"><label for="d-6">6</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-7"><label for="d-7">7</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-8"><label for="d-8">8</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-9"><label for="d-9">9</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-10"><label for="d-10">10</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-11"><label for="d-11">11</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-12"><label for="d-12">12</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-13"><label for="d-13">13</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-14"><label for="d-14">14</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-15"><label for="d-15">15</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-16"><label for="d-16">16</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-17"><label for="d-17">17</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-18"><label for="d-18">18</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-19"><label for="d-19">19</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-20"><label for="d-20">20</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-21"><label for="d-21">21</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-22"><label for="d-22">22</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-23"><label for="d-23">23</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-24"><label for="d-24">24</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-25"><label for="d-25">25</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-26"><label for="d-26">26</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-27"><label for="d-27">27</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-28"><label for="d-28">28</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-29"><label for="d-29">29</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d-30"><label for="d-30">30</label>
</form>
```

Снятие ближайшего чекбоса при установке нового - одним CSS (без скрипта) уже не получится, конечно же.